# What are appropriate return types for a ReactJS Component.render() function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

[The React Tutorial](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/tutorial.html) has a render apparently returning an array of rendered nodes:

```
// tutorial10.js
var CommentList = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    var commentNodes = this.props.data.map(function (comment) {
      return (
        <Comment author={comment.author}>
          {comment.text}
        </Comment>
      );
    });
    return (
      <div className="commentList">
        {commentNodes}
      </div>
    );
  }
});
```

What are acceptable return types for a render() method for a component? An array seems to work? What about an array of arrays? If I have data stored in an array of arrays of codes, how do I appropriately render the grid?

Answer (score 3):

You must always return a react component, but the contents of that component (as long as they are valid jsx syntax) can be an array, an array of arrays containing react components. E.g.

```
var MyComponent = React.createClass({
  render: function () {
    var single = <p>Single</p>;
    var array = [
      <p>One</p>,
      [<p>Two</p>],
      [<p>Three</p>]
    ];

    return (
      <div>
        {single}
        {array}
      </div>
    );
  }
});

React.render(<MyComponent />, document.body);
```

[jsbin](http://jsbin.com/nobiwi/edit?js,output)

Typically you would take the data, iterate over it (however many levels deep) and generate your components. [`Array.Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FArray%2Fmap) and other "functional" helpers are particularly helpful in situations like this.

Comment: You can't currently return an array directly from render, nor an array of arrays.  Your example works because you're returning a <div>.  If you returned `[<div/>]` you'd get `Invariant Violation: ComponentName.render(): A valid ReactComponent must be returned. You may have returned undefined, an array or some other invalid object.`

Comment: @FakeRainBrigand I got distracted by the example code in the OP's question and focused on the _contents_ of the returned component rather than the fact that a component _must_ be returned :) I've updated my answer, thanks for the correction!

Answer (score 1):

If you check the docs you'll see that you can only return a component or null/false from render.

> "The render() method is required. When called, it should examine this.props and this.state and **return a
>   single child component**. This child component can be either a virtual
>   representation of a native DOM component (such as  or
>   React.DOM.div()) or another composite component that you've defined
>   yourself.
>
> **You can also return null or false** to indicate that you don't want
>   anything rendered. Behind the scenes, React renders a  tag
>   to work with our current diffing algorithm. When returning null or
>   false, this.getDOMNode() will return null."

http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html